# Water Hammer on sink hot tap

Tags: plumbing

I have just installed a new washing machine which doesn't require a hot water feed as where the old one did so now that hot water feed is switched off.

Since then the tap on the main sink which is on the same piperun as the old feed has developed water hammer at low flows, is there any way to stop this?

Comment: Depending where you "switched that off" perhaps you could simply open a valve to restore the access to the likely existing arrestor on the washing machine hot pipe run...

Comment: I managed to get a plumber to look at it turned out to be the tap washer which had almost disintegrated as tap was probably 30 years old, I think the upset associated with switching mains water off and on again finally did for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a water hammer arrestor on that line. They are not expensive approx  15$ . These devices have a spring loaded chamber that dampen the water hammer most plumbing and big box stores stock them.  This is the easiest diy method of fixing , if you have access to the pipes strapping them down can also solve the problem.